# QSerialport to Device Communication through COM port(using USB)

Tags: c++, qt

i have one queries regarding Qt. Here in Qt application i am sending packets from PC to DSP board, so comunication from PC to DSP board is working fine, also DSP board sends 3 different packets of different packet size. Communication occurs through COM5 port.

So i just terminal(Tera term) to COM5 port, just to see the packets that we get from DSP board. what i observed in Tera Term is sometimes we will not Get Complete packet at a time ,that means full packet comes in two interval(This is complete packet stats with (E1 and ends with E9) `E1\x01\xFE\x14\x05\x05\xC1Q\x15\t\x02U\x02\xE6\x01\x01\xC2\x01\x01\xE9`). so in tera term at 1milliseconds i get  `E1\x01\xFE\x14\x05\x05\xC1Q` and after 1millisecond i get remaining `\x15\t\x02U\x02\xE6\x01\x01\xC2\x01\x01\xE9.`  so my problem i want complete packet to be sent from DSP board to PC. Port configuration are correct baudrate 115200 and other stuffs related to port configuration are perfect. i want to know what is the reason for my problem.
please tell me the what the problem is

Comment: Serial ports don't know anything about "packets".  They sit at the very bottom of the OSI model, you need a higher level protocol to group the bytes into a packet.  Lots of ways to do that, if it is pure binary data then you'd first send a length byte that allows the receiver to count-off the bytes in the packet.  And you tend to need a specific start byte that indicates the start of the packet, helps you to synchronize the transmitter and receiver.  A checksum tends to be wise at such high baudrates, but then you need more protocol to re-transmit data and you tend to reinvent TCP.

Comment: actuallly my problem is am able to get complete packet from device , but sometimes  what happens is complete packets comes in two interval, so i observed in tera term terminal, so i want to know why sometimes it shows complete packets and sometimes incomplete packet. however device sends complete packets.

Comment: @shashi, Serial port does not guarantee that data bytes which was sent together, will be received together too. You can receive only a part of a data, a "full packet", or even several "packets" together.

Comment: @shashi, therefore you have to: 1. wait for the beginning '(E1'. 2. Wait and read bytes until you receive 'E9)'. 3. Go to 1.